# Indexing null values in Solr

Tags: apache, indexing, solr, lucene

How to index null values field from database in **Solr**?

In my case, I have a record with few fields, which are null. While indexing, that record is not getting indexed, but all other records without null values in all fields are getting indexed properly.

Comment: done by using default values or placeholder in schema.xml

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the fields corresponding to those null values are marked as "Not required" in schema. If you want to index the document with null values, you should provide a default value to those fields in schema. Also, if you are using DIH (Dataimporthandler), make sure that all essential fields which are never null in your source db are imported in the parent entity and the optional fields are indexed in its child entites.